# Get username to show on a label on another form. Need explanation

Tags: c#, winforms, forms

I have 2 forms `Login` and `UserForm`.

On my `Login` form, I have 2 textbox controls, the first is for the username (`txtUser`) and the second for the password (`txtPass`). And I also have a button called `login`.

On my `UserForm`, I have a label called `label1`.

I wanted to take the username's text from `Login`, to show on the label, on form load of `UserForm`.

Please teach me how to do this.

The code of the login is here:

```
public partial class Login : Form
{
    UserForm _userform = new UserForm();
    Admin _Adminform = new Admin();

    public Login()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void loginscs_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string userNameText = txtUser.Text;
            string passwordText = txtPass.Text;
            string isAdmin = "yes";
            string isNotAdmin = "no";

            if (!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtUser.Text)) && !(string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPass.Text)))
            {
                SqlConnection SCScon = new SqlConnection();
                SCScon.ConnectionString = "Data Source=PEWPEWDIEPIE\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT ISNULL(SCSID, '') AS SCSID, ISNULL(SCSPass,'') AS SCSPass, ISNULL(isAdmin,'') AS isAdmin FROM SCSID WHERE SCSID='" + txtUser.Text + "' and SCSPass='" + txtPass.Text + "'", SCScon);

                SCScon.Open();
                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                if (dr.Read())
                {
                    if (this.CompareStrings(dr["SCSID"].ToString(), txtUser.Text) &&
                        this.CompareStrings(dr["SCSPass"].ToString(), txtPass.Text) &&
                        this.CompareStrings(dr["isAdmin"].ToString(), isAdmin))
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Hello " + txtUser.Text, "Admin", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                        _Adminform.Show();
                        this.Hide();
                    }
                    else if (this.CompareStrings(dr["SCSID"].ToString(), txtUser.Text) &&
                        this.CompareStrings(dr["SCSPass"].ToString(), txtPass.Text) &&
                        this.CompareStrings(dr["isAdmin"].ToString(), isNotAdmin))
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Welcome " + txtUser.Text, "User");
                        _userform.Show();
                        this.Hide();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Wrong ID/Pass");
                }
                SCScon.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("error2" + ex);
        }
    }

    private bool CompareStrings(string string1, string string2)
    {
        return String.Compare(string1, string2, true, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) == 0 ? true : false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I suggest to do several things

- Do not hold UserForm in Login form. Just exit application if login failed, or show main form if login succeed
- Separate data access logic form UI logic
- To pass user name to UserForm create UserForm constructor which accepts user name string

Application startup code will look like

```
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Login login = new Login();
    if (login.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK)
        return;

    User user = login.User;
    Form mainForm = user.IsAdmin ? (Form)new Admin() : new UserForm(user.Name);
    Application.Run(mainForm);
}
```

So, as you already noticed I created class User which holds related to user information (except password):

```
public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsAdmin { get; set; }
}
```

Next, I separated data access (moved to repository class) and UI on Login form:

```
public partial class Login : Form
{
    public Login() 
    { 
       InitializeComponent(); 
    }

    public User User { get; private set; }

    private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var repository = new UserRepository();
        User = repository.GetUser(txtUser.Text, txtPass.Text);
        if (User == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Wrong ID/Pass");
            DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
            return;
        }

        if (User.IsAdmin)            
            MessageBox.Show("Hello " + User.Name, "Admin", 
                            MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                            MessageBoxIcon.Information);            
        else            
            MessageBox.Show("Welcome " + User.Name, "User");

        DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    }

    private void RequiredTextBox_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox textBox = (TextBox)sender;
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox.Text))
        {
            errorProvider.SetError(textBox, "Required");
            return;
        }

        errorProvider.SetError(textBox, "");
    }
}
```

I already used controls validating to check if data entered in textboxes (you should subscribe both textboxes to `RequiredTextBox_Validating` event and add `ErrorProvider` component to this form). Next goes data access. Your current code is nice target for [SQL Injection](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) attack. You should use parameters to pass data to database:

```
public class UserRepository
{
    // NOTE: Use <connectionStrings> section in App.config to store connection string
    private string connectionString = "Data Source=PEWPEWDIEPIE\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True";

    public User GetUser(string userName, string password)
    {
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT ISNULL(SCSID, '') AS SCSID, 
                                       ISNULL(SCSPass,'') AS SCSPass, 
                                       ISNULL(isAdmin,'') AS isAdmin 
                                FROM SCSID 
                                WHERE SCSID = @userName ANDnd SCSPass = @password";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userName", userName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", password);

            conn.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (!reader.Read())
                return null;

            User user = new User();
            user.Name = userName;
            user.IsAdmin = reader["isAdmin"].ToString() == "yes";
            return user;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @marc_s yes, already was writing that code, will update in a minute :)

Comment: u guys.. are awesome.. though.. i have no idea what you mean by "Do not hold UserForm in Login form. Just exit application if login failed, or show main form if login succeed"

Comment: @MohdNasrulIwanFajaruddin currently you have `_userform` and `_Adminform` as fields in your login form. That means that login form stays in memory during application lifetime (it is main form in your application). But actually you need opposite - you need user or admin forms to be main forms of your application and define application lifetime. Login form should be used just to login user before showing main form.

Comment: you... should do C# classes.. and i will attend it everyday.... how i wish my lecturer could explain to me like this...

Comment: sorry , but my project's due is this friday , and if i miss this , i'll fail my diploma, and i dont want to change my code that much as i am not certain with changes. *as the last pre-presentation , my project crashes infront of the classes and laptop went to bluescreen for no reason*

Comment: @MohdNasrulIwanFajaruddin basically you should be able to use this code. Just add `public UserForm(string userName)` constructor to user form and rename button on login form. I will be afk for several hours. I think you can ask questions on StackOverflow if you will face some problems

Comment: Thank you so much! Im sticking around anyway.. :)

Answer (score 0):

If u like to stick with your code:

- Add a label property to your UserForm class.
- Override OnLoad() in your UserForm class. Here you insert your label property value into the UserForm's label 'this.label1'.

Now create the instance of UserForm, set its label property and show the form...

The Load event of a form is triggered just before it is displayed for the first time.
When overriding, make sure you are calling the base member from inside the overridden eventhandler (e.g. base.OnLoad(e) since registration of events occurs in your base class (in this case the Form class) and not in the derived class (your UserForm) )